# Could this code to concat address, be improved any further?

Tags: c#

Could this code be improved any further?
may be by keeping it simple but avoid to create a list from object values

```
public static string GetAddress(Address address)
{
    if (address is null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    List<string> addressLines = new List<string> {
        address.Line1,
        address.Line2,
        address.Town,
        address.Country,
        address.Postcode
    };

    IEnumerable<string> addressLinesWithValues = 
        addressLines.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l));

    return string.Join(" ", addressLinesWithValues.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Remove `.ToArray()`.

Comment: This has been useful. I have removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I would call it an improvement, but it does remove the `List` creation:

```
public static string GetAddress(Address address)
{
    return address == null
        ? string.Empty
        : $"{(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address.Line1) ? "" : $"{address.Line1} ")}" +
          $"{(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address.Line2) ? "" : $"{address.Line2} ")}" +
          $"{(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address.Town) ? "" : $"{address.Town} ")}" +
          $"{(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address.Country) ? "" : $"{address.Country} ")}" +
          $"{(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address.Postcode) ? "" : address.Postcode)}"
              .TrimEnd();
}
```

---

Another option that reduces the number of lines but keeps the same functionality/implementation is:

```
public static string GetAddress(Address address)
{
    return string.Join(" ", new List<string>
    {
        address?.Line1,
        address?.Line2,
        address?.Town,
        address?.Country,
        address?.Postcode
    }.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)));
}
```

Comment: I prefer your second option. Thanks :-) .

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it this way. This will result in fewer allocations, and in my opinion is much easier to understand.

```
string result = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",
    address.Line1,
    address.Line2,
    address.Town,
    address.Country,
    address.Postcode);
return result.Replace("  "," ");
```

Depending on the data you have to work with, you may need to account for the possibility of triple spaces, not just double. Quadruple seems very unlikely.

Note also that this code will remove double spaces that are *within* a field (for example, if an address is`1000      Broadway Ave` it will change it to `1000 Broadway Ave`) but that actually may be more of a feature than a bug.

Comment: @RufusL That is what I was referring to when I said "you may need to account for the possibility of triple spaces." But in most cases (in the U.S. at least) the only field that might be blank is `Line2`, so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest an override on your 'Address'. That way, there will be no need for a method written specifically for your once used case (address prop values join).

To get the address joined as a string, just do Address.ToString();

```
public class Address
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var joinedAddress = $"{this.Line1} {this.Line2} {this.Town} {this.Country} {this.Postcode}";
        return Regex.Replace( joinedAddress, @"\s+", " " );
    }
}
```